# How can I create users in a ASP.NET membership table without using CreateUser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to migrate users and posts from an existing forum I am using to a ASP.NET membership table without using CreateUser. Basically I want to maintain userIDs so that when I migrate posts they continue to associate with the correct users. Is there a way to do this or would I be better off just using CreateUser and then finding a way to re-assign the post-by-UserIDs to the correct new IDs?

Thanks

Comment: how about backing up and restoring the whole Users table (including IDs)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a UserProfile table that you can use to join from the User table to your Post table. This will insulate you from the ASP.NET Membership Provider's internals and can be an extension point for additional user information.

Here's a stored procedure and associated functions that I use to create new users and their profiles:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateUser] 
  @UserName nvarchar(256)
, @ClearTextPassword nvarchar(128)
, @Email nvarchar(256)
, @PostingID uniqueidentifier

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @ApplicationName nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @PasswordFormat int
DECLARE @UnencodedSalt uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @Password nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @PasswordSalt nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @Now DATETIME
DECLARE @UniqueEmail int

SET @ApplicationName = 'YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME'
SET @PasswordFormat = 1 
SET @UnencodedSalt = NEWID()
SET @PasswordSalt = dbo.base64_encode(@UnencodedSalt)
SET @Password = dbo.base64_encode(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 
   CAST(@UnencodedSalt as varbinary(MAX)) 
   + CAST(@ClearTextPassword AS varbinary(MAX)) )) 
SET @Now = getutcdate()
SET @UniqueEmail = 1


BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier

EXECUTE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_CreateUser] 
   @ApplicationName
  ,@UserName
  ,@Password
  ,@PasswordSalt
  ,@Email
  ,NULL
  ,NULL
  ,1
  ,@Now
  ,@Now
  ,@UniqueEmail
  ,@PasswordFormat
  ,@UserId OUTPUT

INSERT INTO [dbo].[UserProfile]
(
 [UserID]
,[PostingID]
)
VALUES
(
 @UserId
,@PostingID
)

COMMIT  

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[base64_decode] 
(@base64_text VARCHAR(max)) 
RETURNS VARBINARY(max)

WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN

DECLARE @x XML; SET @x = @base64_text 
RETURN @x.value('(/)[1]', 'VARBINARY(max)')

END

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[base64_encode] 
(@data VARBINARY(max)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)

WITH SCHEMABINDING, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN

RETURN (

SELECT [text()] = @data 
FOR XML PATH('')

) 
END
```

Comment: you don't actually use your base64_decode function here but it's nice to have i guess.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is I would create a link table between your user's table and ASP membership table where membership ID (email address?) would be related to UserID (Integer?). Then I would  build a routine for creating users and populating membership table with users data programmatically - it is a little easier to do through .NET code.